# how can I send additional data when set value in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to send 2 data at the realtime database.
One for write at the database, the other for checking the write rules not for update.
{a:b} must be write at the database if {c:d} information is sending together.
Is it possible at the realtime database?

I tried it but failed.

```
database.child("users").setValue(account)

data class account(Id: String, admin: Bool)
```

but I don't want to update admin information

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass an object to the database and then only get some properties of that object written.

If you only want to set the `Id` property in the database you can either call `setValue` at the right path like this:

```
ref.child("Id").setValue("newId");
```

Or alternatively, you can pass a map of the value(s) to update with `updateChildren()` like this:

```
var updates = mapOf("newId" to "Id")
ref.updateChildren(updates)
```